# Do the Borg assimilate non-sentient creatures?

Tags: star-trek, borg

Fairly simple question, if the Borg were to say assimilate the Earth would the wildlife be in some way assimilated too or would it simply be exterminated? Are there any instances of this happening?

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe; [If the Borg assimilate a planet of idiots, does the Collective become dumber?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/if-the-borg-assimilate-a-planet-of-idiots-does-the-collective-become-dumber)

Comment: I saw that, while an animal would have no "technological distinctiveness" to add there's still the possibility of there being worthwhile physical properties.

Comment: The Borg wouldn't even assimilate the Kazon, so it seems unlikely that they'd be interested in assimilating non-sentient creatures.

Comment: This question spawned a humorous scene in my mind where a guy with a shotgun is in the woods hunting for deer... he see the deer, but as he lifts up his gun to aim, the deer raises its head from foraging and turns to face him, revealing a laser implant which paints a bright red dot right on the hunter's forehead...

Comment: The Borg assimilate spaceships, if that answers your question ;)

Comment: @T-1000'sSon As I said the Borg didn't see anything worth having in the Kazon's technology or biology, but I fail to see any reason that they wouldn't assimilate a primitive race if it had interesting physical traits

Comment: I appear to have been duped. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39898/borg-assimilation-of-non-sapients?rq=1

Comment: What about their attempt to assimilate Species 8472 ships? Would that count?  They're alive but I don't think that they are self aware?

Answer (score 19):

### Main Canon

Within the main canon there are no examples of the Borg successfully assimilating anything other than [sentient, bipedal, humanoid creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20274/why-are-there-no-non-humanoid-borg?rq=1).

That being said, there's no reason to assume they *couldn't* assimilate them, if the mood took them and they saw a benefit in doing so. Otherwise they'd just **ignore them or kill them if they presented a threat.**

---

### Extended Universe (EU)

Within the novel [The Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_(Shatner_novel)) (written by none other than William Shatner) Picard encounters some **assimilated *dogs***.

> Two dogs—sleek Dobermans, pets of the personnel who had been assigned
>   here, no doubt, trotted past. But they did not stop to investigate.
>   **Bioneuronic implants studded their skulls. Biomechanical tubes were
>   grafted to their chests.**
>
> One dog turned to look at Picard as it passed. One eye clear though
>   expressionless, so unlike the breed. **The other eye had been replaced
>   by a laser sensor.**

Comment: That said, how are the cybernetic dogs supposed to be one voice with the collective?  "We are the Borg.  Resistance if fUUUUUUUUUUtile."

Comment: Let's not forget assimilation goes both ways. That means the collective is part doberman, according to Shatner.

Comment: It frankly seems ridiculous that the Borg would assimilate dogs.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Go tell that to Shatner.

Comment: Assimilated dogs.... y'know, mechanical zombies are two for two and don't really scare me that much (although _First Contact_ was a tour de force of subtle horror) but show me an assimilated dog and I swear to god I will cry for my mother

Comment: One wonders what biological and technological distinctiveness a Doberman could possibly add to "[their] own", mind you

Comment: They might not have been full members of the Collective, just controlled soldiers.

Otherwise all it would take is a few squirrels to distract the Collective long enough to defeat them.

Comment: One day, the Borg assimilated a cat, and then they started sleeping 20 hours a day and chasing their own laser eye bling thingies.

Comment: Isn't "EU Canon" an oxymoron?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - You're not wrong

Comment: Dear god The Return is a terrible book.

Comment: @ench - It is far from the worst Star Trek EU novel. Very far indeed.